# How to increase Y axis limit on matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-widget

```
def doAnchoreGraph(image):
    print(image)
    info = infoAnchoreLog(image)
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title('Report '+ image)
    window.geometry("1000x1000")
    data = {'CVE': ['1. CRITICAL','2. HIGH','3. MEDIUM','4. LOW'],
                'Frequency': [info[1],info[2],info[3],info[4]]
            }
    df = DataFrame(data,columns=['CVE','Frequency'])
        
    figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(9,8), dpi=100)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    bar = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, window)
    bar.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
    df = df[['CVE','Frequency']].groupby('CVE').sum()
    df.plot(kind='bar', legend=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title("Scanned Image: "+ image)
    
    filename = "anchorescan-" + image + ".png" 
    figure.savefig(filename)
```

Anyone knows how to increase the limit of the Y axis? mine is capped at 20 for some reason. Here's  my sample output:
[doAnchoreGraph.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oJo1.png)

Comment: `ylim` is the function you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

`ax.set_ylim(start,end)` should do the trick.

Comment: You should add a bit more clarification of what this method does.